# Changing an image with AJAX and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have an image file in HTML that I am trying to update with different images that come in, specifically the latest.
Here is the Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/uploads/update_file',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_file():
    print('update_file')
    list_of_files = glob.glob(staging_dir+'/*.jpg')
    if len(list_of_files) == 0:
        latest_file = ''
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    print('latest '+latest_file)
    splits = latest_file.split('/')
    file = splits[-1]
    return send_from_directory(directory=staging_dir, filename=file)
```

In the java script I have:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
       setInterval(ajaxCall,5000);

     function ajaxCall()
      {
          $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : "{{url_for('update_file')}}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        document.getElementById("img").src = data;
                    },
                 });
      }
</script>
```

What I see is update_file() gets called but send_from_directory never seems to return.  I assume so because update_file is only called once.  Any idea what is wrong or is this even the preferred way about going about this?

Comment: On the line " file = splits[-1]" , what is the output for print(file) , and print(type(file)) . In your ajax call, inside the success function , what is the output of console.log(data) , console.log(typeof(data)) . In your ajax call I see you have a "success: " . Could you also add an "error: " section and print out the error if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is quick solution that does not make use of send_from_directory(), but it works.

I am basically using the same same code you have in your post. Removed the logic to check for the latest file( to keep this demo simple ).

```
@app.route('/uploads/update_file',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_file():
    item = ["static/img/"+item for item in os.listdir("static/img")]
    return random.choice(item)
```

This is my folder structure :

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Great, I was able to get it working.  I did have one issue though, I couldnt use relative paths like  "static/img", I had to do "os.listdir("/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/server/static/img"". This is running from a pycharm debugger.  Any idea how to avoid that?